# UTM tag issue in Parameter Manager (Web Analytics Connector)

Tags: marketing-cloud, parameters, web-analytics-connector

I was just testing the parameter manager in Marketing Cloud. All utms I need are shown in the link when I send an email via journey builder. But now I noticed that there is a weird code added after each utm tag. Does anyone know how I can remove this code (or what caused it to show up)?

- This is the utm code I added in the parameter manager: `utm_medium=email​​&utm_source=marketingcloud​​&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%​​&utm_term=%%linkname%%​​&utm_id=%%jobid%%​​&sfmc_id=%%subscriberid%%`
- These are the utm tags that are shown after the link: `...?utm_medium=email%e2%80%8b&utm_source=marketingcloud%e2%80%8b&utm_campaign=promotional-newsletter-Testing%e2%80%8b&utm_term=button%e2%80%8b&utm_id=18063%e2%80%8b&sfmc_id=14790197`

As you can see, the code `%e2%80%8b` shows up after `email`, `marketingcloud`, etc.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Did you copy & paste that value in parameter manager? Are there possible any LF/CR if so?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you copy and paste it notepad like a pure text editor(not really pure)it will work. It would be awesome if you can manually type it, but again SFMC should not allow hidden encoded content to be saved.